# A script to toggle WiFi in MacOS

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to write a script that toggles WiFi on or off.

I'm having trouble with the "if" statement. I'm starting with a simple script that should tell you if Wifi is on or off. It doesn't work as written. I get "Wifi is off" no matter what the WiFi status is

```
#!/bin/sh
STATUS=`networksetup -getairportpower en0`
if $STATUS == On
then
   echo "Wifi is on"
else
    echo "Wifi is off"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Thou shall use [ expr ] to evaluate the logical expression. So, the condition would be like:

```
if [ $STATUS == On ]
```

If you need to evaluate some more elaborated expression, you may use [[ expr ]]. Meaning of both is explained in [this section of bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

The text value from `networksetup` is not just "On" it is (on my machine) "`Wi-Fi Power (en0): On`".  Therefore we need to take into account the text before "On", which we can do with a *glob pattern*, the asterisk (*) means "zero or more of any character".  For that we need the double `[[` command in our `if` statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
status=$(networksetup -getairportpower en0)
if [[ $status == *On ]]
then
    echo "Wifi is on"
else
    echo "Wifi is off"
fi
```

Other notes:  I used `#!/bin/bash`, rather than `sh`.  `sh` is a POSIX shell, which is (arguably) a subset of bash.  If you want `bash` then you should specify it on the `#!` line, not `sh`.

I used the `$( )` notation rather than back-ticks ( `` ).  Back-ticks are considered deprecated and difficult to read.

Note the spaces around and within `[[` and `]]`, they are required.

I have replaced STATUS with `status`.  This is because there are many uppercase variable names used by the shell so using uppercase risks a name collision.  Best to use lower or mixed-case variable names.

Comment: Excellent. That worked for me and I learned a lot from your answer.